# Change target of symlink without deletion

Tags: qt, symlink, qfile, qfileinfo

Is it possible to change contents of symlink using `Qt`?

Static `QFile::link` and non-static one both return `false` if linkname filepath is already exist.

I just want to retarget symlink. An analogue of `ln -sf`, but crossplatform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

To quote the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#link):

> This function will not overwrite an already existing entity in the file system; in this case, link() will return false and set error() to return RenameError.

The solution is rather straightforward: First remove the link explicitely, e. g. using [`QFile::remove()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#remove) on **the link**, then use `QFile::link()` for the targeted file (as you already did).

BTW, `ln -f` with or without `-s` is doing nothing else than calling `unlink()`. This can be seen conveniently in the [BusyBox sources (line 128)](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/coreutils/ln.c?h=1_27_stable#n128), while in the [GNU coreutils](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/ln.c;h=e86f581b9e0dd52465adf18f7b980b3f66daf5e4;hb=e9d231112a6ae4eead78ecf462a34d7f31bd503a) it's a bit more obfuscated.

Comment: What's this, a test whether I'm able to recognize trick questions? If you already know the answer, and think it's important for subsequent readers to know, why don't you write your own complementing answer? And if you want someone else to answer it, you should add that point to your question, or better create a new one.